# show alert if months/years in two strings are different

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web-services

i am creating a web app in mvc-5 angularjs,

i need to show data of the following date entered by the user(in textboxes(i have two textbox)), but the user can only fetch the data of 1 month like, if i want to see data i can enter(01-01-2016) to (31-01-2016) or (29-01-2016) to (31-01-2016)

i a user enter the date like (31-01-2016) to (03-02-2016) then the alert will be shown with the error or if he enters the date like (01-01-2016) to (31-01-2017), then also the alert should appear, 
my webservice will validate the data in following strings(`frmdate and dateto`)

what i need to do here?

Comment: use getmonth(),getyear() and try to compare both and then show your alerts based on result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to find the difference between the From date and To date and check whether the difference is 30 days or 31 days depending upon your logic.

Save those date strings as Date objects.

```js
var fromDate = new Date($scope.fromDate);
var endDate = new Date($scope.toDate);
```

In order to use a Date object in any sort of calculation, we must first retrieve the Date's internal millisecond value, which is stored as a large integer since you can't just add or subtract Date objects together.

```js
// Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var fromDate_ms = fromDate.getTime();
  var endDate_ms = endDate.getTime();
```

Then Calculate the difference in milliseconds

```
var difference_ms = endDate_ms - fromDate_ms;
```

To obtain the number of days for a given number of milliseconds, we would divide by 86,400,000, the number of milliseconds in a day (1000 x 60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours):

```
var differene_days = Math.round(difference_ms/86400000);
```

If `differene_days` is equal to 30 or 31 show the report else show error message.